# Azure web app running slow (.NET 6) compared to VPS

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, vps

I have 10 .NET 6 microservices that are deployed on Azure as web apps. I am using the B1 App service plan (1 CPU and 1.75GB of RAM) for all of them in the West Europe region. The problem is that all of them are simply too slow to respond. I have created the `/healthz` endpoint for checking if the service is alive, and whenever I call it, it takes 300+ ms to respond (sometimes even 1+ s). When I use any of these apps in a "normal" use case, doing some CRUD operations, it always takes more than a second to complete a simple GET query. The database is on a completely different server and hosting provider, and I assume it is not a problem only because the `/healthz` endpoint is also very slow and literally does nothing. Here is the output of the `top` command from one of the services.[image: Web App stats]

On the staging environment, I have one VPS located in Europe with 20 running Docker containers (all.NET services and all other services, including databases, RMQ, etc.), and it is running smoothly (the `/healthz` endpoint takes no more than 100 ms on any of the services). We have been through the beta testing phase with a load of 10–20 concurrent users, and all of the services worked with no performance issues at all. Here is the current output of the `htop` command:
[image: VPS stats]

I tried to change the app service plan to B3 (4 CPU and 7GB RAM), but there were no changes. I set *Always On* to *On* for all of the apps.

The main question for me is: how can a VPS with 20 running containers and the whole infrastructure be faster than a dedicated web app running only a single.NET 6 application? It is also worth mentioning that I have many Spring applications on different Kubernetes clusters running on not more than 300 MB of RAM and half a CPU, and they are lightning fast compared to these on Azure. Am I doing something wrong, and if so, should I change the approach, the hosting provider, or something else?

Comment: Are these app service plans Windows or Linux?

Comment: All of them are Linux app service plans. Btw we have moved all services to Google Cloud and they are much faster.

Comment: I've been running load tests between Windows and Linux Web Apps with a .Net6 app and have noticed the Linux version is much slower.  It almost seems like network latency, similar to what you're describing.  If you're able to and curious I'd be interested in knowing if the issues go away when you switch to using an Windows App Service plan.

Comment: Good catch. I will definitely try it out just because I am curious. From the customer's point of view, it kinda makes sense. Windows plans are more expensive if I am correct so if you pay more, you get more.